# Zeitwerk collapse namespacing to root level

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zeitwerk

Zeitwerk's readme gives this example for collapsing namespaces:

> booking.rb                -> Booking
>
> booking/actions/create.rb -> Booking::Create
>
> To make it work that way, configure Zeitwerk to collapse said directory:
>
> `loader.collapse("#{__dir__}/booking/actions")`

But I don't want to cut out the middle, I want to bring everything to root level namespacing.

I.e. instead of `Booking::Actions::Create` or `Booking::Create` I just want `Create`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`collapse` just removes the last directory in the path given, so if you want to remove two directories, run `collapse` for each directory.

E.g.

If you have `/app/a/b/c/d.rb` then you can bring `d.rb` up to no namespacing with:

```
loader.collapse("app/a/b/c")
loader.collapse("app/a/b")
```

Zeitwerk will look at `d.rb` as if it's within `app/a/`, and all subfolders of `app/` are considered root level

Comment: This is technically true, but we do not know if this is the right solution to the actual situation (I am the author of Zeitwerk). Hence my questions above.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for making such awesome code :)

The example in the question was from the Zeitwerk's readme example. The actual use case for me is an older Rails project that had a lot of code in `/lib`, that I moved to `/app/lib` for Zeitwerk to automatically load. But the code was broken into sub directories for organization purposes (but without namespacing any of the classes).  E.g. `/app/lib/validators/date_validator.rb` or `/app/lib/presenters/csv/csv_client_presenter.rb`

So my solution was `autoloader.collapse("app/lib/*/*", "app/lib/*")`, would you do it differently?

Comment: No, in that situation collapsing seems perfect, because those directories exist for legacy reasons and they do not represent the root namespace in a conceptual way, their only purpose was organization.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to define `/path/to/booking/actions` as a root directory. Does that make sense in your application?

Comment: How would I do that, could you give an example please?

Comment: Is that a Rails application? I would also like to understand first why do you want `booking/actions/create.rb` to define a top-level `Create` constant. That is strange.

Comment: The example is a bit strange, I wouldn't want a Create root level constant. But I'm dealing with old code that has a `CsvClientPresenter` available at root level instead of `Presenter::Csv::Client`. I could restructure everything to use namespacing, but I would prefer to have minimal changes if possible.

Comment: Another option would be to remove the intermediate directories, but if the structure in directories is helpful, you can leave them. That is up to your judgement. Take into account, though, that if you wanted namespaces in `app/lib` in the future, you'd need to replace the wildcards with something else.